# Qué quiere decir "Tu #image debe estar centrado dentro de su padre."

Tags: html, css

Soy realmente nuevo en esto, estoy haciendo un proyecto que es hacer una página tributo en Freecodecamp, por lo que me dice "Tu #image debe estar centrado dentro de su padre". Tendré errores….sin embargo, estoy aprendiendo, gracias.

```css
#img-div {
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

#image { 
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 330px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código quedaría así, conservando los margin top y bottom:

```
#image {
      margin-top: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 24px;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: auto;    // Este es el cambio a tu codigo 
      margin-right: auto;   
            }
```

Cuando especificas `auto`  básicamente le dices al navegador que determine automáticamente los márgenes izquierdo y derecho,dentro de su contenedor principal o "padre".